# How to bind a Dictionary to Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

When I bind `FoundItems` dictionary to a ComboBox, ComboBoxItems items became like `[1, FoundItem], [2, FoundItem] ...`.

But I want to bind `RecordName` as shown value, `RecordID or Dictionary's Key` as selected item. 
And, `SelectedItemID` should be bound to the ComboBox with `TwoWay`.

I am trying to achieve this for 2 days. And still no result.

```
public int SelectedItemID { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, FoundItem> FoundItems { get; set; }


    FoundItems = new Dictionary<int, FoundItem>
    {
        { 1, new FoundItem() { RecordID = 1, RecordName = "Test Name 1" } },
        { 2, new FoundItem() { RecordID = 2, RecordName = "Test Name 2" } },
        { 3, new FoundItem() { RecordID = 3, RecordName = "Test Name 3" } },
        { 4, new FoundItem() { RecordID = 4, RecordName = "Test Name 4" } }
    };
```

**FoundItem class:**

```
internal class FoundItem
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public string RecordName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FoundItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.RecordName"
          SelectedValuePath="Value.RecordID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItemID}"/>
```

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. It certainly works for me. The code you have posted won't even compile. FoundItem cannot be internal. Post your *real* code if you somehow still cannot make this work.

Comment: That class is internal because i will obfuscate this code later. Everything works fine with other classes (internal class and public properties). I dont want to write whole code but I think I can share a compilable sample.

Comment: You can't expose a public Dictionary<int, FoundItem> property if FoundItem is an internal type.

Comment: I've found the problem. The problem was a silly written App.xml template for ComboBox. I've removed the custom template for ComboBox, everything is working fine.